# time.Time Round to Day

Tags: go

I have a timestamp coming in, I wonder if there's a way to round it down to the start of a day in PST. For example, ts: `1305861602` corresponds to `2016-04-14, 21:10:27 -0700`, but I want to round it to a timestamp that maps to `2016-04-14 00:00:00 -0700`. I read through the time.Time doc but didn't find a way to do it.

Comment: Does [`Time.Truncate`](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time.Truncate) not do what you want?

Comment: Truncate is another option, I think it's more of a pain to implement however because you have to create a `Duration` to represent the hours, minutes, seconds and nanoseconds.

Comment: Time.Truncate only works if you want UTC, AFAICT

Comment: May be [Time.Round](https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/go1.19.3:src/time/time.go;l=1518) will do the trick?

Answer (score 99, accepted):

The simple way to do this is to create new `Time` using the previous one and only assigning the year month and day. It would look like this;

```
func truncateToDay(t time.Time) time.Time {
    return time.Date(t.Year(), t.Month(), t.Day(), 0, 0, 0, 0, t.Location())
}
```

here's a play example; https://play.golang.org/p/jnFuZxruKm

Answer (score 43):

You can simply use duration `24 * time.Hour` to truncate time.

```
t := time.Date(2015, 4, 2, 0, 15, 30, 918273645, time.UTC)
d := 24 * time.Hour
t.Truncate(d)
```

https://play.golang.org/p/BTz7wjLTWX

Comment: Note that truncate always truncates against UTC, so if your timezone is not UTC, the resulting time will not be 00:00 in that timezone.

Comment: `t.Zone()` will return the difference to calculate
https://play.golang.org/p/UIhTnurbayW

Comment: Do not use this one! The first comment is right - From Truncate() documentation - 
// Truncate operates on the time as an absolute duration since the zero time; it does not operate on the presentation form of the time. Thus, ```Truncate(Hour) may return a time with a non-zero
minute, depending on the time's Location.```

Comment: It also states that: `The rounding behavior for halfway values is to round up.` So you might get next day when time is afternoon.

Answer (score 8):

I believe the simplest is to create a new date as shown [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36988882/3778355).
However, if you wanna use time.Truncate, there is two distinct cases.

## If you are working in UTC:

```golang
var testUtcTime = time.Date(2016, 4, 14, 21, 10, 27, 0, time.UTC)
// outputs 2016-04-14T00:00:00Z
fmt.Println(testUtcTime.Truncate(time.Hour * 24).Format(time.RFC3339))
```

## If you are not, you need to convert back and forth to UTC

```golang
var testTime = time.Date(2016, 4, 14, 21, 10, 27, 0, time.FixedZone("my zone", -7*3600))
// this is wrong (outputs 2016-04-14T17:00:00-07:00)
fmt.Println(testTime.Truncate(time.Hour * 24).Format(time.RFC3339)) 
// this is correct (outputs 2016-04-14T00:00:00-07:00)
fmt.Println(testTime.Add(-7 * 3600 * time.Second).Truncate(time.Hour * 24).Add(7 * 3600 * time.Second).Format(time.RFC3339))
```

Answer (score 3):

I using theses functions on all my projects:

```golang
package time_utils

import "time"

func TruncateToStartOfDay(t time.Time) time.Time {
    return time.Date(t.Year(), t.Month(), t.Day(), 0, 0, 0, 0, t.Location())
}

func TruncateToEndOfDay(t time.Time) time.Time {
    return time.Date(t.Year(), t.Month(), t.Day(), 23, 59, 59, 0, t.Location())
}
```

Answer (score 1):

in addition to sticky's answer to get the local `Truncate` do like this

```
t := time.Date(2015, 4, 2, 0, 15, 30, 918273645, time.Local) 
d := 24 * time.Hour
 fmt.Println("in UTC", t.Truncate(d)) 
_, dif := t.Zone() 
fmt.Println("in Local", t.Truncate(24 * time.Hour).Add(time.Second * time.Duration(-dif)))
```

Answer (score 1):

```golang
func truncateToDay(t time.Time) {
    nt, _ := time.Parse("2006-01-02", t.Format("2006-01-02"))
    fmt.Println(nt)
}
```

This is not elegant but works.