# How to update hour, min, sec in golang time?

Tags: go, time

Ex: How can I update hour in `t` time?

```
fmt.Println(t)
//=> 2006-01-02 15:04:05 +0000 UTC
```

Expect to get: `2006-01-02 00:00:00 +0000 UTC`

Edited: similar to: [time.Time Round to Day](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36988681/time-time-round-to-day)

Comment: Similar problem like this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36988681/time-time-round-to-day

Comment: What you want to do exactly? Can you please elaborate the problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [time.Time Round to Day](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36988681/time-time-round-to-day)

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Use:

```
t1 := time.Date(t.Year(), t.Month(), t.Day(), 0, 0, 0, t.Nanosecond(), t.Location())
```

Ref: https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Date

Answer (score 10):

This seems to do it:

```
package main

import (
   "fmt"
   "time"
)

func main() {
   t := time.Now().UTC()
   t = t.Truncate(24 * time.Hour)
   fmt.Println(t)
}
```

https://golang.org/pkg/time#Time.Truncate